# D3.js: How can i change xlink:href image after "if..else" Statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

i'm try to use `d3.js` change each image with different skill value.
but don't know why the return value can't return the image.

Update 2016/02/05:
it seems ignor ajax function

and when i See my Developer Tool.i got this HTML result:

```
<g transform="translate(844,478)">
    <pattern class="sNodes" id="image2" width="100%" height="100%">
        <image id="node_id31" width="50" height="50"></image>
    </pattern>
    <circle r="25" class="sNodes" id="node_id31" fill="url(#image2)" onclick="NodesDownInlv3(31)" indicator="4-n-12-S05"></circle>
    <text class="sNodes" id="node_id31" style="text-anchor:middle" x="10" y="30">4-n-12-S05</text>
</g>
```

The image `xlink:href` attribute not in the image.

Here's the JS Code about `xlink:href` part:

```
elemEnter.append('pattern')
                    .attr('class', d.class)
                    .attr('id', function() {
                        if (d.class == "bNodes") {
                            return 'image';
                        } else {
                            return 'image2';
                        }
                    })
                    .attr('width', '100%')
                    .attr('height', '100%')
                    .append('image')
                    .attr('xlink:href', function() {
                    return 'images/star_03.png'; //this return is work
                        var img;
                        if (d.class == "bNodes") {
                            return 'images/star_01.png'; //this is work
                        } else {
                            //return 'images/star_02.png';
                             //console.log(d.node_sn);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'php/data_Skill.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {
                                    node_sn: parseInt(d.node_sn)
                                },
                            })
                                .done(function(data) {
                                    var arr_data = data.split(";");
                                    arr_data = arr_data.filter(function(str) {
                                        return /\S/.test(str);
                                    });

                                    arr_data.forEach(function(index) {
                                        index = index.split(',');
                                        console.log(index);
                                        var ind = index[0];
                                        var skill = parseInt(index[1]); //skill = 0, 15, 20, 52, 70, 100
                                        console.log(ind, skill);
                                        var indicate_id = d.indicate_id.split("("); 
                                        indicate_id = indicate_id[1].split(")");
                                        indicate_id = indicate_id[0]; //indicate_id = "4-n12-S05" ,ind="4-n-12-S05"
                                        //console.log(mapSN)
                                        //image = 'images/star_02.png';
                                        if (indicate_id == ind) {
                                            if (skill == 0) {
                                                img = 'images/star_02.png';
                                            } else if (skill == 15 || skill == 20 || skill == 52 || skill == 70) {
                                                img = 'images/star_04.png';
                                            } else if (skill == 100) {
                                                img = 'images/star_03.png';
                                            } else {
                                                img = 'images/star_02.png';
                                            }
                                        }else{
                                            img = 'images/star_02.png';
                                        }
                                    })
                                })
                         return img; //this not work
                        }
                    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible way to fix this issue.

1) Set `async: false` to the ajax request.

OR

2) Create the image elements first and then set the image url as shown below.

```
d3.selectAll("pattern").selectAll("image").each(setImageUrl);
function setImageUrl(d) {
    var imageEl = this;
    d3.select(imageEl).attr("xlink:href","images/star_03.png");
    if (d.class == "bNodes") {
        d3.select(imageEl).attr("xlink:href",'images/star_01.png'); 
    } else {
       $.ajax({
          url: 'php/data_Skill.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
             node_sn: parseInt(d.node_sn)
          },
     }).done(function(data) {
          var img;
          var arr_data = data.split(";");
          arr_data = arr_data.filter(function(str) {
             return /\S/.test(str);
          });
          arr_data.forEach(function(index) {
              index = index.split(',');                  
              var ind = index[0];
              var skill = parseInt(index[1]); //skill = 0, 15, 20, 52, 70, 100
              var indicate_id = d.indicate_id.split("("); 
              indicate_id = indicate_id[1].split(")");
              indicate_id = indicate_id[0]; //indicate_id = "4-n12-S05" ,ind="4-n-12-S05"
              if (indicate_id == ind) {
                   if (skill == 0) {
                      img = 'images/star_02.png';
                    } else if (skill == 15 || skill == 20 || skill == 52 || skill == 70) {
                      img = 'images/star_04.png';
                    } else if (skill == 100) {
                      img = 'images/star_03.png';
                    } else {
                      img = 'images/star_02.png';
                    }
               }else{
                    img = 'images/star_02.png';
               }
        });
        d3.select(imageEl).attr("xlink:href",img);
      });         
   }
 }
```

I personally prefer second option more.

Comment: doesn't work!! Don't know why the function are jump over

Comment: You have to find the image url first and set it after that. Ajax takes some time to get the server response. You have to set attribute asynchronously inside the function.

Comment: And there was one accidental mistake in my code. The attribute should have been set inside done callback function. Sorry. Have a try now.

Comment: Great!it's work but seem's loading is too heavy.
any suggestion to make it better?

Comment: May be because of the delay in getting the ajax response. Try to optimize your query.